# I need an alternative to WSS which does not require any certificate for signing in

Tags: websocket, passwords, salt, wss

I have ws working for sending user login details through a websocket. However I know that someone sniffing packets could capture the password, so I wanted to use wss instead. However I now understand, through playing around with my back end, that firstly a certificate is required for it to connect properly, and secondly, if i cause the self signed certificate warning to sho0w, afterwards the websockets will work with wss, but that is not good enoyugh for clients. From googling this issue, I have found that A self signed certificate will probalby not be good enough.

And all I want is to provide a user with a safe way to login.....
So anyway I am now thinking it would be better to avoid having to use wss all together. I could use a conventional servlet for login but that will probably require a certificate too for https and I don't want to have to start paying people loads of money for certificates when my business might not even be that successful.

I have been thinking about other ways I could send the users password securely. One way might be to generate a hash in the browser. I know I could use some king of challenge along with a salt sent to the browser but I am not exactly sure how to do this and how safe this would be. I have the conventional login working with a salt, generating a hash with AES. Any suggestions?

I just want the users login details to be safe and I don't want to go down the route of certificates, it's annoying and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Login should always happen through HTTPS. Not only the POST sending the user and password, but also the GET getting the login form, so the client can be sure is getting the right form and that his information will be posted to the right place.

You can send login details either by HTTPS or WSS if you want security. If you use a self-signed certificate you will provide transport security, but as the certificate is not signed by a CA, the client cannot be sure that the server with which is interacting is the right one, and that is why the browser shows a warning.

So, if you want security for your clients, **you should get a signed certificate** and use it for HTTPS and WSS (you can get them from 10 bucks per year in some places). Anything that you do in the browser is insecure by default, starting by the user not having certainty of being interacting with the right server and not a spoofed one.

Comment: may I ask if you know how I go about putting the certificate into my netbeans project. I can get a cir or crt file. I have googled this and just keep running upon information about applet certificates which I already know how to do :/?

Comment: like no shit dude, I don't think all this is even worth the effort. I go on a site to get my certificate and it wants me to verify my domain with an email. So for that I need to set up a mail sever. I set up smtp server but can not install any of the pop severs for the incoming message i have tried as the windows server 2012 vps wont install .net framework 2 or 3.5. I do everything to try to install that it still doesn't work. It's just one pointless battle because some greedy nothing decided it was a good idea to create this stupid paid certificate greed concept.

Comment: What about using a Google account as login? That way you have secure login done elsewhere. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?hl=en Once the authentication happens, your server can return a cookie that the WebSocket connection will attach to the request, so you can refuse connections without an authentication cookie. Still, not using certificates is unsafe for your clients, but at least you would not sent user/passwords in plain text over the wire.

Comment: i got mailenable working on my vps:), so i got past the verification for getting a certificate. Now all I have to do is generate the csr and it looks straightforward! Google for sign in is  a good idea but I wanted this to be a learning experience and the actual programming part of it I find easy, I already have the database working nicely the hashes being generated all that and I enjoyed writing it.  I might include oaft at some point!

Answer (score 0):

Found this blog helpful even though it's directed to the raspberry pi and python/nodejs. http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/09/5-ways-to-secure-websocket-rpi.html

Good concepts on security and authentication.  I would recommend ALWAYS using ssl and not rolling your own crypto.